# Define services parameters inside a sf4 bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle, symfony4

I'm trying to configure a service inside a bundle.  This service needs some parameters from the.env file but I can't declare these parameters in the service. Here's my code:

src/Dfc2/WsBundle/Services/WsManager/WsManager.yaml

```
parameters:
    wsAdminUser: '%env(WSADMIN_USER)%'
    wsAdminPassword: '%env(WSADMIN_PASSWORD)%'
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    WsManager:
        public: true
        class: App\Dfc2\WsBundle\Services\WsManager\WsManager
        arguments:
            $env: '%kernel.environment%'
            $wsAdminUser: '%wsAdminUser%'
            $wsAdminPassword: '%wsAdminPassword%'
```

src/Dfc2/WsBundle/Services/WsManager/WsManager.php constructor:

```
public function __construct($env, RequestStack $requestStack, SessionInterface $session, string $wsAdminUser, string $wsAdminPassword)
{

    $this->environement = $env;
    $this->wsAdminUser = $wsAdminUser;
    $this->wsAdminPassword = $wsAdminPassword;
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->baseUrl = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getBaseUrl() . WsParameters::URL_SUFFIX;
    $this->setBaseUrl();

}
```

And this is the error message I get.

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Dfc2\WsBundle\Services\WsManager\WsManager": argument "$wsAdminUser" of method "__construct()" must have a type-hint or be given a value explicitly.
```

I don't understand what's wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: Try to use `autowire: false` on service definition.

Comment: In your service definition, replace the id WSManager with the fully qualified class name: App\Dfc2\WsBundle\Services\WsManager\WsManager and then you can delete the class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mathieu Dormeval and Cerad,
I changed my service definition like this and now it works:

```
services:
    App\Dfc2\WsBundle\Services\WsManager\WsManager:
        autowire: false
        public: true
        arguments:
            $env: '%kernel.environment%'
            $requestStack: '@request_stack'
            $session: '@session'
            $wsAdminUser: '%wsAdminUser%'
            $wsAdminPassword: '%wsAdminPassword%'
```

Comment: Glad it is working.  No need for autowire false and no need for public true.  Nor do you really need to specify the objects request stack and session.  Autowire can be powerful.  It's worth taking the time to understand what it can and cannot do.  And on an unrelated note, always be careful with using $request = $requestStack->getCurrentRrequest() in a constructor.  Your service might be constructed before the request processing is complete.  Generally best to ask for the request when you actually need it.  And beware of possible sub requests.